# JSF 1.1-Calling action method of backing bean without page refresh(through ajax/javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

i am using JSF1.1. in my jsf application,i have a select dropdown and onChange of this dropdown i am calling a javascript function(changeCompany)
which performs button click event(in below code snippet currCompany is the hidden command button) to fire action method of backing bean. but by doing this, webpage is getting refresh because of this click event.
 so i want to call action method of backing bean without page refresh(by javascript or ajax in JSF 1.1). i have to strictly use JSF1.1 with IE-8 and chrome-version 28.
is there anyway to call action method of backing bean by javascript ?
how i can implement this using ajax(as per my knowledge jsf 1.1 has no/limited support for ajax (with IE8 and chrome-28))?
Please suggest.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="" id="currCompany" onchange="changeCompany();">
  </h:selectOneMenu>

function changeComapny()
{
document.getElementById("abc:xyz:currCountry").click();
}

<h:commandButton value="" id="currCountry" action="#{BeanClass.ActionMethod}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to see this previous post : [Ajax with Jsf 1.1 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473911/ajax-with-jsf-1-1-implementation)

The best solution though would be to migrate to a newer version of JSF.

Comment: Thanks Thrax for ur reply,can we use a4j library with IE-8 and chrome-version 28?

Comment: @user3498659 From the documentation, it supports IE 5-7. Nothing about Chrome. See : http://ac.aua.am/Cis/Avsl/Literature/Jsf/ebooks/Ajax4JSF/developerGuide.html#SupportedBrowsers. But I'd say it'll be pretty much compatible.